# running imported module functions through sockets in Maya (Python)

Tags: python, function, sockets, import, maya

I have a problem and I am not sure what is going on, I have created a 'userSetup.py' file and placed it in the script folder (C:\Users*user*\Documents\maya\2022\scripts)

This is my userSetup.py file:

```
def importPy():
    ### import modules and open a command port ###
    exec("import my_module", globals())
    exec("cmds.commandPort(name=':1234', sourceType = 'python')")
    exec("print('FINISHED')")

def tryImport():
    """
    execute importPy when Maya is idle
    """
    from maya.utils import executeDeferred
    executeDeferred("importPy()")

tryImport()
```

now I have created a file 'my_module.py' and placed it in the same script folder

this is the my_module.py file:

```
print("my_module loaded")

def function_print(statement: str):
    print(statement)
```

I know this is working on startup as the console in Maya reads:

```
my_module loaded
FINISHED
```

I have a successfully sent over simple commands like:

```
cmds.polyCube()
```

it works fine even returns fine which I found odd since I am not echoing the output, so the socket server is working as intended. But if I send:

```
my_module.function_print("please print this")
```

it doesn't work, but it will work if I write that exact same line in the python command line within Maya.

This doesn't really make sense to me, I am fairly new to python so I may be missing something obvious here. But all I can think is that the socket commands somehow don't have access to the global scope.

If anyone knows what's up with this, it would be much appreciated.

Thanks,
Brendan

P.S. the names to my modules and functions have been made up for this example. If that wasn't obvious.

Comment: I'm not a experienced user concerning commandPorts, but it could be possible that it executes the commands in a new environment so that is has no knowledge of your module. You could try to send a command like this: `source my_module;my_module.function_print("please print this")` to check if my assumption is correct.

Comment: yes, that does work. Thanks for your help. I assume that there is no way around this?

Comment: I guess I could set the scripts location in an environment variable. My script/project idea is slowly getting closer and closer to plug-in territory and that is a whole can of worms I am hesitant to get into.

Comment: In theory all commands you import or define in the userSetup.py should be available in a running maya. So if you put `import my_module` in the userSetup, it should be possible to call the function in it without sourcing it every time.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm doing, and it works when I call it in the command line in Maya. But it doesn't work when I call it externally via sockets.